# CriticalIOException when trying to call web service

Tags: http, blackberry

I'm having a little trouble trying to make an HTTP connection on my Blackberry Torch 9800. Here is the line where the problem occurs:

```
HttpConnection connection = (HttpConnection)Connector.open(URL);
```

My phone has no data plan and I was trying to do this through wifi. I've been doing it fine this way for a few months now. But suddenly it's giving me a `CriticalIOException`.

Here is my connection string:

```
http://mysite.mycompany.com/mws/MyWebService/MyWebService.asmx;interface=wifi
```

I don't know why this is happening and I don't know what to do about it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Check this link, `How to make a basic http connection by just wifi without any data plan?` - http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/How-to-make-a-basic-http-connection-by-just-wifi-without-any/m-p/632418#M131259

Answer (score 1):

Please, please don't keep using that legacy `Connector.open()` approach. This was the way connections were opened in JavaME, and since RIM built its libraries on top of them, they came up with a suffix-based hack to select the transport type. this caused dirty code prone to break, and caused so much pain to new developers (and also senior ones).

RIM introduced `ConnectionFactory` in OS 5.0 specifically to solve this kind of problems. This was back in 2008, guys we're in 2012!

[Have a look at it](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/io/transport/ConnectionFactory.html).

Answer (score 0):

Typically when using the wifi appender, the deviceside appender is used as well.  I'm not sure if this is related to your problem, though.

```
 ;deviceside=true;interface=wifi
```